# How to reset drop down list back to default when there is nothing in textbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a textbox #Email and I have two dropped down list menus that is #Carriers and #Phones. When the Email is entered I want to enable only Carriers drop box but not the Phones. When the Carriers is selected the Phones dropdownlist has to be enabled. The Phones dropdownlist can only be enabled when there is an email and carriers selected. If user enters email and selects an item from #carriers and #phones and then email is erased the two drop menus have to be disabled. The way I want it to work is when user selects items from #carriers and #phones and then deletes email both drop down menus have to be disable and set back to default. Right now it only disables but doesn't set them back to default.

```
      <!-- Will check for e-mail and enable #carrires dropdownlist, otherwise, it will disable dropdownlist for #Carriers-->
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Email').on('input change', function () { //check to see if email is empty
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#Carriers').prop('disabled', true);//disable carriers when there is no email
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true); //will keep Phones disabled when there is no email
        }
        else {
            $('#Carriers').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```
    <!-- Will check for Carriers selected and enable the Phones dropdown list-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { //check if carriers is selected
    $('#Carriers').change(function () {
        if ($('#Carriers').val() == '') { //if empty
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true); //disable
        }
        else {
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', false); //enable
        }
    });
});
```

```
     <!--this row carrier and phones-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Carriers)
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Carriers, new SelectList(ViewBag.Carriers, "ID", "Carrier1"), "Select a Carrier", new
           {
               @disabled = "disabled",
               data_bind = "value: Request.Carriers",
               @class = "form-control",
               data_width = "95%",
               data_toggle = "tooltip",
               data_placement = "top",
               title = "Requested Plan Carrier"
           })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Carriers, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phones)
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Phones, new SelectList(ViewBag.Phones as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "PhoneID", "Name"), "Select a Phone", new
               {
                   @disabled = "disabled",
                   data_bind = "value: Request.Phones",
                   @class = "form-control",
                   data_width = "95%",
                   data_toggle = "tooltip",
                   data_placement = "top",
                   title = "Requested Equipment"
               })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phones, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I wrote something that if there is input inside the textbox, then it will enable the two select optons, if not, then it will not only disable, but also reset the drop boxes to default.

I hope you like it, comment if you need more help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Email').on('input', function () { //check to see if email is empty
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#Carrier, #Phones')
          .prop('disabled', true).each(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
          });
      } else {
        $('#Carrier')
        .prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
    $("#Carrier").on('input', function () {
      $("#Phones").prop('disabled',false);
    });
 $("#Email").trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="Carrier">
 <option value="default">Please select a carrier</option>
 <option value="1">AT&amp;T</option>
 <option value="2">Verizon</option>
 <option value="3">Cricket</option>
 <option value="4">Ting</option>
 <option value="5">Sprint</option>
</select>

<select  id="Phones">
 <option value="default">Please select a device</option>
 <option value="1">Android</option>
 <option value="2">iPhone</option>
 <option value="3">Blackberry</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="Email" />
```

Comment: I'm getting my phones and carriers from the database. It's just the way it's set up. Where are you getting 'input' from?

Comment: I made up the carriers and phones as an example.  Just ignore the HTML part.  I was primarily talking about your JavaScript.

Comment: However, you do need to add a default option if you don't already have one.

Comment: Where do I add the default? The above code missed up my site. It doesn't enable the #Carrier when email is entered.

Comment: Did you try it on the run code snippet, does that work as needed?

Comment: Yes, it did on the code snippet. That's what I need mine to do.

Comment: I need help with the razor view. I'm new to it and I have no idea where to put a default. The one that you did is html which I understand.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  How about instead of doing that, we simply have it automatically select the first option (the one that will display by default when you open a webpage).

Comment: That works! However, now I need to figure out how to enable the carrier first when user enters email address. Once user selects a carrier enable the dropdown list for phones. If you user deletes email, carrier and phone have to be set back to default. The top code was working for me except that is wasn't setting them back to default.

Comment: I tried your code and I entered the email and both drop down list did not enable. It works in the code snippet but not in my program. I modify my code to implement your default and it now works. Thank you so much for your help! I will post my answer below and comment on it.

Comment: Do you happen to know any bootstrap, nfn neil?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!-- Will check for e-mail and enable #carrires dropdownlist, otherwise, it will disable dropdownlist for #Carriers-->
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Email').on('input change', function () { //check textbox on input change
        if ($(this).val() == '') {//check to see if email is empty
            $('#Carriers, #Phones').prop('disabled', true).each(function () { //disable #carriers and #Phones dropdown list when no email is entered
                $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val()); //"option:first" will set the dropdown list back to default when no email is entered
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#Carriers').prop('disabled', false); //else if there is email it will enable the dropdownlist for carriers
        }
    });
});
```

```
    <!-- Will check for Carriers selected and enable the Phones dropdown list-->
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Carriers').change(function () {//dropdown list for a change
        if ($('#Carriers').val() == '') {//if no carrriers is select
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true).each(function () {;//disable dropdownlist for #Phones
                $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', false); //else enable Phones once Carriers is selected
        }
    });
});
```